# How to do automatic translation in code from different strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, internationalization

I have 2 languages: Spanish and English in my app.
I have put the corresponding values in Translations Editor in Android Studio.

In xml, I just give text a string like this:

```
@string/player_title
```

and, depending on the language, it automatically displays the English or Spanish equivalent.

But in java, when I give the default value, like this:

```
textView.setText(R.string.player_title);
```

it does not yield same result!
How do I make Translations Editor place corresponding translation for me?

Comment: Normally, you do so by putting 2 different strings.xml in 2 folders: `res/values-en` and `res/values-es`. The former one can be left as `res/values`, so English will be the default.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, thx Frank, this is 2nd time you answer my questions.